# Is CWnd::ScreenToClient safe?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, mfc

I am currently making a lot of use of code like this in order to determine a control's location within a window's client area:

```
CRect rect;
GetDlgItem(IDC_CONTROL_ID)->GetWindowRect(&rect);
ScreenToClient(&rect);
```

All is working fine, but I'm concerned about the safety of this code. Specifically, if the user moves the window in between `GetWindowRect` and `ScreenToClient` due to the thread containing the above code being suspended by Windows, will it produce the wrong results? If so, is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user won't be able to move the window at all while your code inside of a message handler function is executing. So no, this will not be a problem.

The UI is basically temporarily frozen or suspended while your code is running. Technically, this is because Windows is unable to process other messages until you return. The message loop starts running again once you return from your message handler function, thus returning control.

This is, of course, why you shouldn't execute code that takes a long time to run (e.g., complex calculations) inside of your message handlers because the UI will be frozen until it finishes.
Instead, you should spin off a separate thread to run this kind of stuff. Since you're not multi-threading here (and don't need to because this code takes a negligible amount of time to execute), there will be no re-entrancy problems.

Comment: A more technical explanation: all threads that show windows have a message queue associated to them and are created by the operating system when needed. The message queue receives all the messages, including the messages generated for move events. The message queue essentially serializes the messages so that the window doesn't move until you (or MFC) processes the move messages. So the results of `GetWindowRect()` would still be valid, unless it's being called on a window the thread doesn't own.

Comment: Are you disagreeing with my answer, @Insilico? Or just adding additional information? Yes, the messages will be effectively serialized, but that won't affect the back-to-back execution of the `GetWindowRect` and `ScreenToClient` functions.

Comment: I'm just adding a bit more information. I agree with your answer 100%.

Comment: It's sufficiently right. A simple explanation is that moving a window takes a `WM_MOVE` message, which cannot be handled between these two function calls. (And a more complex explanation would explain how you can have a multi-threaded UI ;) )